# how to change vs code python extension's language?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My computer's system language is zh_cn, so the vs code python extension set the default language to chinese. But i want to change the language to english. 
I can't find the reference in the doc or on the internet. Anyone konws how to do it? Thank's for help

PS: vs code's locale is alreay set to english.

Comment: have a look at this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales) from official VS Code.

Comment: I've opened a bug for VSCode: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/62623

Answer (score 0):

When VScode is open go to View menu and select Command Palette. Once the command palette is open type display in the box. This should display the message configure display language. Open that and you should be in a local.json file. The variable local should be set to en for English.

Comment: I have the same problem, just python extension shows in my OS language. The locale is set as English. This solution does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed other python extensions for VSCode. Microsoft official python extension will follow the `locale` setting in user/workspace settings.
Try uninstall other python extensions, you may see it changes to English.